# How to implement alert overlay feature in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I have one image and it's related text ans one uibutton , I want to display the image and it's related text and uibutton into it, I want to open this in overlay feature, how I can achieve this in iphone any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Try: [TSAlertView](https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView).  It will allow you to put up customized alerts.

Comment: TSAlertView link can not open?

Comment: Sorry.  Link fixed.  Stack overflow added characters.